# Struts 2 Custom Exception Handling

Tags: exception, struts2

I am a newbie to Struts 2. I am using the Apache Struts 2 documentation for learning Struts 2.

I need a tutorial for custom exception handling in Struts 2; where should I look?

Comment: What specifically are you wanting to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend the [guides](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/guides.html); they cover most functionality, including [exception handling](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/guides.html).

The nutshell version is that the "exception" interceptor handles Struts 2 declarative exception handling. You can declare both global and exception-specific exception handlers. Each specifies the exception to handle and the result to be returned if the exception is caught:

```xml
<!-- Here the results are expected to be global results. -->
<global-exception-mappings>
    <exception-mapping exception="java.sql.SQLException" result="SQLException"/>
    <exception-mapping exception="java.lang.Exception" result="Exception"/>
</global-exception-mappings>

<!-- Here an action configuration adds an addition exception handler. -->
<action name="DataAccess" class="com.company.DataAccess">
    <exception-mapping exception="com.company.SecurityException" result="login"/>
    <result name="SQLException" type="chain">SQLExceptionAction</result>
    <result>/DataAccess.jsp</result>
</action>
```

If you have further questions after that, you'll need to be more specific.